# Can we get the elements in the middle of "stack" directly?

Tags: c, memory, stack, local-variables

*Think of the situation as follow.*

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    int a=10; //a get into the stack.
    int b=20; //b get into the stack.
    int c=30; //c get into the stack.
    ...
}
```

*As we know, the “stack segment” is satisfied with the storage approach of "stack data structure"; and here, the local variables a, b, and c are exactly stored in such a direction of memory, so in theory we can only access to the element at the top of the stack.*

*But what if we do something like this?*

```
printf("b = %d",b);
```

*Local variable b is in the middle of a and c, but we can get it.*

*So...can we say that we can directly get the element in the middle of the stack?*

[*Here is the image of " **a, b, and c stored in stack** "*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dR3B.png)

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking. Whether the compiler puts the value of the variables in the stack is implementation dependent. If there is no need to, the compiler might not even put this values in the stack but in a register. As a programmer you don't need to worry about these things, the compiler knows how to retrieved the value for `d` in the `printf`.

Comment: I mean, the data structure "stack", which is known as the storage approach of "LIFO", and we can imitate this kind of data structure (even though in different languages the specific implement will be different. e.g. in C, we usually use struct but in Java we use a class to imitate the "stack"). Since a "stack" is created, it should followed the principle of "LIFO". But here as you see, when we try to access the local variable b, we can easily get it, even it is stored in the middle of a and c in that "stack" data structure. How can that be?

Comment: You're confused. The C standard doesn't use the word "stack."  It requires only that an activation of a C function provide new storage for parameters and local variables. Some implementations, for example, have chosen to do that with a linked list of non-contiguous blocks of memory. Many do use a stack, but all the variables for an activation are allocated in a single block, typically accessed with respect to a register (sometimes called base or stack pointer).  Your question is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

> the local variables a, b, and c are exactly stored in such a direction of memory

I don't know from where you got this but this is not true, at least in modern compilers.

First of all, C itself doesn't specify anything about using a stack. How the function calls are implemented is implementation defined. Lots of common implementations use stack like data structure to implement function call in the sense that last called function will be returned first.

But this doesn't mean that the local variables are stored in stack like structure. There are lots of options to the compiler like:

1. It can eliminate the variable completely if that is not needed in run-time.
2. It can place the variables in register.
3. It can re-order variables.

In all of these cases the only thing that compiler guarantees that the observable behavior of the code is not changed.

Since it doesn't store variables in stack like data structure, it has no problem to access them in middle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all C standard never utter stack` anywhere. Now moving from standard - implementors may implement such a way that local variables are stored in stack memory as part of function frame.

Now you are thinking - stack is always accessed on top but here we can access the variable `b` directly. Though it is in the middle somewhere. Nope you are wrong - the thing is the frame of the functions are which are stored in stack and popped off when done(though an implementation can do it other way also - but speaking in general). It is not the variables that are the unit of operations here.

By accessing `b` we are not violating any rule of stack data structure. The function frames are the ones which are accessed in `LIFO` manner not the variables inside those frames.

Also it's a bit out of context now a days to segregate like that. We can simply say that they have automatic storage duration. And that's it. They can be implemented in group of registers also(standard won't stop them). The function frames are the one which will likely to be have that stack data-structures behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of the stack to store automatic variables is only an implementation detail, nothing is required by the standard. But at a lower level it is indeed the most common implementation. It is because in processors, a special register (stack pointer) is used to store return addresses in function calls (instructions call and return). When automatic variables are also stored in that stack, it is trivial to reclaim there storage back at return time or at end of the block. But they are not individually pushed onto a stack: a frame pointer is used to store the memory zone for the current block (including a reference for upper frames) and the stack pointer is increased in one single operation for the size of the frame containing all the local variables. Then those variables are known by the offset to the current frame pointer. So they are known by their own address and not as elements of a stack.